# Generic method with genric argument and return type

Tags: java, generics

I would like to create a generic method with a return type that contains a generic element sent in to the method. 
This works fine as long as the input argument is of exact same type as the generic type. However I would like it to be possible to send an extension of the generic type.

Basically, I would like to create a method, *createList*, that would work for both of these calls:

```
List<Object> list = createList("foo");
List<String> list2 = createList("bar");
```

This generic method below **works fine for the second call**, but not for the first one.

```
private static <T> List<T> createList(T element) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(element);
    return list;
}
```

For the second call I get a compilation error saying "Incompatible types. Required Object. Found String".

Below is the non-generic version which **works fine for the first call**, but not for the second:

```
private static List<Object> createList(Object element) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(element);
    return list;
}
```

Same compilation error here as on the other version but this time String is required, and Object was found.

Is it possible to create a method (preferrably using generics) in a way that both these calls would work? (using Java 7)

Comment: You haven't written your own class called `Object` have you?  Or imported an `Object` class from some weird library?  Your compilation error suggests that `Object` here doesn't have the usual definition.

Comment: You can just cast to object: `createList((Object)"foo")`

Comment: I can reproduce with Java 7, this works fine in Java 8 though. So the answer is to update.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem No, it is the standard Java Object (java.lang.Object).

Comment: @JornVernee I need it to work with Java 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some type inference changes in Java 8 that fix this problem. So the straightforward solution is to update.

If you can't or don't want to update to Java 8, you can also provide the generic type explicitly:

```
List<Object> list = EnclosingClass.<Object>createList("foo");
```

Where `EnclosingClass` is the class that declares `createList`.

Comment: Thanks, providing the generic type works perfectly. (I can't update to Java 8)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similiar, and solved the problem using a method like this.

Also this is not limited to any certain "Type" of Elements. It allows Every Object and/or primitive. IT also gives you a one-liner to fill a created list with some elements.

```
    @SafeVarargs
    private static <T extends Collection<S>, S> T makeList(T collection, S... objects) {
        Collections.addAll(collection, objects);
        return collection;
    }

   //example:
   List<String> list1 = makeList(new LinkedList<String>(), "foo", "bar");
   List<Integer> list2 = makeList(new ArrayList<Integer>(), 1,2,3,4);
```